# Print function is printing nothing inside call function in Keras/Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to print some objects inside below call function using print command but it prints nothig when the code runs successfully. I am reading ([THIS](https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/debugging_tips/)) keras debugging tutorial but still I am confused why it is not printing anything.

```
#Hyperparams 
learning_rate = 0.001
weight_decay = 0.0001
batch_size = 100 
num_epochs = 1

image_size = 72  # We'll resize input images to this size
patch_size = 6  # Size of the patches to be extract from the input images
num_patches = (image_size // patch_size) ** 2
projection_dim = 64
num_heads = 4
transformer_units = [
projection_dim * 2,
projection_dim,
]  # Size of the transformer layers
transformer_layers = 8
mlp_head_units = [2048, 1024]
```

I want to print the (positions and encoded) inside below call function. For that I used print but it's not working. while [HERE](https://keras.io/examples/keras_recipes/debugging_tips/), they had done like this.

```
class PatchEncoder(layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, num_patches, projection_dim, position_embedding):
  super.__init__()
  self.num_patches = num_patches
  self.projection = layers.Dense(units=projection_dim)
  self.position_embedding = layers.Embedding(
    input_dim=num_patches, output_dim=projection_dim
  )

  def call(self, patch):
  positions = tf.range(start=0, limit=self.num_patches, delta=1)
  encoded = self.projection(patch) + self.position_embedding(positions)
  print("Encoded shape is:",encoded.shape)
  print("pos.shape is:", positions.shape)
  return encoded
```

Comment: Try `tf.print('something')`.

Comment: @Kaveh Sir I tried this like `tf.print('pos.shape:', encoded.shape)` but it is also not printing anything after execution.

Comment: Adding `run_eagerly=True` parameter to your `model.compile()` function may resolve the issue. But it is not a good solution since it may make your algorithm run slower.

Comment: Somehow I understood this point. I found [HERE](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Layer) the implementation of run eagerly mode using `daynamic=True` argument. I tried like `def __init__(self, num_patches, projection_dim, position_embedding, dynamic=True):` and `super.__init__(dynamic=True)` and `def call(self, patch, dynamic=True):` and `print("Here it comes:",encoded.shape, dynamic=True)` but no output so far!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the code shared in the comments.  Add this as the first code cell before the imports.

```
%%bash
pip install -U tensorflow_addons
```

Add a yo in the routine of interest

```
class Patches(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, patch_size):
        super(Patches, self).__init__()
        self.patch_size = patch_size

    def call(self, images):
        print("yo")
        batch_size = tf.shape(images)[0]
        patches = tf.image.extract_patches(
            images=images,
            sizes=[1, self.patch_size, self.patch_size, 1],
            strides=[1, self.patch_size, self.patch_size, 1],
            rates=[1, 1, 1, 1],
            padding="VALID",
        )
        patch_dims = patches.shape[-1]
        patches = tf.reshape(patches, [batch_size, -1, patch_dims])
        return patches
```

Run the cell for printing the sample image and the yo will print.

```
yo
Image size: 72 X 72
Patch size: 6 X 6
Patches per image: 144
Elements per patch: 108
```

Comment: Thank You for your helpful answer, I read that in tensorflow 2.x `tf.executing_eagerly()` is enabled by default. When printed `print(tf.executing_eagerly())` in my colab, it printed True.

Then I found [HERE](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/executing_eagerly) in Tenserflow docs that, Eager execution is enabled by default However, this API might return False when executing inside `tf.function`, unless under `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` is previously called.

Then I executed `tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)` before `class PatchEncoder` but no output so far.

Comment: Yes, hence why I said it depends upon your particular version of tf.  Have you tried to do any simple prints?  ie. just a simple program with your install/setup?  Lastly, since you don't show your entire code, perhaps you need to verify that PatchEncoder() routine is actually being called.

Comment: I run vision transformer model in Keras. It's complete code is availabe [HERE](https://colab.research.google.com/github/keras-team/keras-io/blob/master/examples/vision/ipynb/image_classification_with_vision_transformer.ipynb). I am very new to Keras but during documentation I found same thing (printing objects) inside functions using above strategy.

Comment: Ok. I just did that code and I was able to print in the specified routine. I modified it slightly.  See above for my edits.

Comment: Thank You Sir for Your valuable time. I tried Your code in `Patches` class and it prints (yo and other image dimension) details. But I want to print `encoded = self.projection(patch) + self.position_embedding(positions)` this line in `PatchEncoder` class, Have you tried printing this?

Comment: Also `print("yo")` is printing when I defined it in `Patches` class but when I define `print("yo")` in `PatchEncoder` class then it is not printing.

Comment: My apologies. I just saw this now and I deleted that collab.  If its not being called in the other routine, you will need to determine why the routine is not being called.  Update your question with your results and I will try to debug that way.

Comment: Well I first thought, if it's possible to print objects in this way in tensorflow, I don't know how they represented it in keras docs but they did not call objects and printed inside functions. 
I first printed it by calling them and generated shape of (144, 64) but then I was confused because in encoded they have added positions to patches but vector dimension is still same (64) this made me more confused.
I thought if tensorflow has some printing objects inside functions to get accurate shapes and I am getting wrong shapes by calling these objects outside functions.

Comment: But @netskink Thank You Sir for clarification and your answer helped me to undersatand my question.